# Angular subcomponent separates table header from table rows

Tags: angular, html-table, subcomponent

Consider the simple Angular 16 project constructed as follows : `ng new`, followed by
`ng g c sub` (thus creating a new component called sub), modifying the
AppComponent class in app.component.ts to become `export class AppComponent {indices=[1,2]}`, modify the contents of `app.component.html` file to become

```
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" hidden>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th> </th>
    <th>Product Name</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let index of indices">
     <app-sub></app-sub>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and finally, modify the contents of `sub.component.html` file to become

```
<td><input type="radio" name="radioGroup"></td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Quantity : 1
<button > + </button>
<button > - </button>
</td>
```

It would seem (at least to me) that all this should be equivalent to the following HTML file :

```
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" hidden>
    <table>
        <tr>
          <th> </th>
          <th>Product Name</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="radio" name="radioGroup"></td>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Quantity : 
            1
            <button > + </button>
            <button > - </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="radio" name="radioGroup"></td>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td> Quantity : 1
            <button > + </button>
            <button > - </button></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

But as a matter of fact, the outputs are different on my PC, see
below :

The html output in the browser (which is what I want) :

[image]

The Angular output in the browser :

[image]

Is there some improvement I can make on the Angular code to deal with
this ?